# Why doesn't this break statement work as intended?

Tags: java, break

I have this simple snippet of code with a break statement. I was trying to solve this http://codeforces.com/contest/787/problem/B. I came up with this solution:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    FastReader in = new FastReader();
    int n = in.nextInt(), m = in.nextInt();
    HashSet<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
    for(int i=0;i<m;i++){
        set.clear();
        int k = in.nextInt();
        boolean cancel = true;
        for(int j=0;j<k;j++){
            int cur = in.nextInt();
            if(set.contains(-cur)){
                cancel = false;
                break;
            }
            else set.add(cur);
        }
        if(cancel && k!=0){
            System.out.println("YES");
            return;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("NO");
}
```

It didn't pass the tests, but the moment I remove the break statement after the cancel  =  false; line. It works. I can't seem to explain what the different between having the break statement so that when the first time you found -cur inside set you would change cancel to false then break and just assign false to cancel everytime you find -cur inside set and wait till the loop end and not break.

Comment: The `break` statement applies to the *inner* loop. And `cancel` is false, so the outer loop continues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you break out of `for(int j=0;j<k;j++)`, you don’t read all the `k` numbers of that line of input (unless you were already at the last number).

For example, consider this input:

```
2 2
3 -1 1 -2
1 2
```

After having read -1 and 1, you program sets `cancel` to `false` and breaks out of the inner loop. Next time through the outer loop it will read -2 into `k`, and you’ve got it messed up.

When you remove the `break` statement, you are reading all the numbers correctly, and your program therefore works correctly.

Comment: Thank you I should of got that.